# Log4J2 - assigning user specific file appender filename at runtime

Tags: xml, eclipse, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to use the XML config file in LogJ4 2 to log to a file somewhere in my projects folder. This is a shared project so I can't just code in the complete path to the desired location. 
The path has to be dynamic based on the machine the program is compiled on so that the log file will be generated properly at all times.

I've read multiple approaches to this on here but none of them have worked for me.

Here is my overall structure: 
src: log.class
config folder: log4j2.xml
logs: Id like the log file to be written in here

XML Source code looks like this:

```
<properties>
    <property name="logFilePosition">${sys:logFilename}</property>
</properties>
```

and

```
<File name="OutputFile" fileName="${logFilePosition}" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %m; %n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
</File>
```

also

```
<Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="trace" />
        <AppenderRef ref="OutputFile" level="trace" />
</Root>
```

I have also tried it with `fileName="${sys:logFilename}"` which doesn't work either. 
This XML is not complete but relevent parts are shown.

My Log class looks like this:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log.class.getName());
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);

// Returns current location based on individual location
private static URL location = Log.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
private static String final_location = location.toString().substring(6, location.toString().length());

    Log(){
        // Sets system property required for XML configuration file in order to reference desired output location
        // of log file by the use of "logFilename"
        System.setProperty("logFilename", final_location+"logs/mylog.log");

        //LoggerContext ctx =   (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
        ctx.reconfigure();
```

If I'll just do `System.out.println(final_location+"logs/mylog.log");`, the correct path is shown. If I just copy this path and pase it directly into the XML file, a log file is generated.

Problem seems to be that outside the Log() constructor, like in other methods in this class, the property "logFilename" is null. How can I bypass this ?

What am I missing here? Id really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked quite a while ago I'm just now reading it and I have a solution that is working. It seems the problem lies with the timing of when the system property is defined. You're invoking log4j2 APIs before setting the system property by doing things like this at the top of your class:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log.class.getName());
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
```

If you're also calling methods on the `logger` before you set the system property (before you call the constructor - perhaps in a static method) then of course you will see that the property is null.

The solution is to ensure that you define the system property before you start using log4j. Here is a working example:

```
package example;

import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

public class Log4j2JvmProp {

    //This static block will run before anything else and ensure that the system property is
    // set before log4j is initialized or used.
    static{
        URL location = Log4j2JvmProp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        String final_location = location.toString().substring(6, location.toString().length());
        System.setProperty("logFilename", final_location+"logs/mylog.log");
    }

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    static LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j2.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="logFile" fileName="${sys:logFilename}" immediateFlush="false"
            append="true">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As the comments in the code state, when this is run the static block will execute first and set the system property before anything else occurs. Even if you call a static method on this class from some other class the static block still executes first because it runs when the class itself is loaded.